# Nginx ( Openresty ) Proxy, Adding custom headers to static files

Tags: nginx, proxy, configuration

I'm trying to add headers to static files , How can I do it properly ?

I tried nesting but didn't work

```
server {


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://apache.backend.local/;
        proxy_no_cache $http_pragma $http_authorization;

        proxy_cache radish_cache;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_cache_control;
        add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

        proxy_redirect          off;

        proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;

        proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires;

        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding '';
        proxy_set_header Connection '';
        proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
        proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;

        proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;

        proxy_connect_timeout 59s;
        proxy_send_timeout 600;
        proxy_read_timeout 600;
        proxy_buffer_size 64k;
        proxy_buffers 16 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 128k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;

        location ~* \.(3gp|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|wmv|avi|asf|asx|mpg|mpeg|mp4|pls|mp3|mid|wav|swf|flv|exe|zip|tar|rar|gz|tgz|bz2|uha|7z|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf|iso)$ {
            gzip_static off;
            #add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
            access_log off;
            expires 30d;
            break;
        }

        location ~* \.(js)$ {
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
            access_log off;
            expires 10d;
            break;
        }

        location ~* \.(css)$ {
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
            access_log off;
            expires 10d;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

also tried not nesting and include proxy configuration in each location then I get this error

```
"proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except"
```

I'm using latest openresty

Comment: Remove the trailing `/` from your `proxy_pass` statement. That is the "URI part" that the error message is highlighting.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks mate , That was it , Could you post it as answer so I can accept it , cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trailing `/` on the `proxy_pass` statement is the "URI part" mentioned in the error message.

In your configuration file, you have:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://apache.backend.local/;
    ...
}
```

Translating `/` (from the `location`) to `/` (from the `proxy_pass` statement) is pointless - so the "URI part" is unnecessary and should be removed.

When you attempted to implement `proxy_pass` in various *regular expression* `location` blocks, the "URI part" triggered the error message. But as you do not need `proxy_pass` to perform any URI translation, you can safely remove the trailing `/`.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.